# How to stop this command from exit-ing the terminal

Tags: command-line, compiling

I'm working with building tarballs, and in order to estimate how long other builds will take I need to time the first one. However, every time I try to time this command, the terminal exits as soon as it completes, and I cannot read the results. This is the command:

```
time { . ../configure \
    --prefix=/tools \
    --with-sysroot=$LFS \
    --with-lib-path=/tools/lib \
    --target=$LFS_TGT \
    --disable-nls \
    --disable-werror && \
    make && \
    case $(uname -m)
     in  x86_64) mkdir -v /tools/lib && ln -sv lib /tools/lib64 ;;
    esac && \
    make install; }
```

Why is this resetting the terminal, and how do I stop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
time { . ../configure \
```

You're sourcing `configure`! Every command in it is then run in the current shell, instead of a subshell. If `exit` is encountered, the shell will exit. Did you mean:

```
time { ../configure \
```

Comment: Maybe. But the shell seemed to be reaching the `make` steps. I'll double-check.

Comment: Happy to report that it seems like that was the mistake. The book had in a paragraph earlier stated that one should create a build subdirectory, but it presented it like it was optional; so when I saw `../configure`, plus the way the PDF was encoded, it looked like they had meant `. ./configure` for people who had ignored the optional part. I'm currently re-running the command and hopefully it'll work. :)

Comment: @BHustus If you're building GCC, running `configure; make` in a different directory is the recommended way: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC

Comment: Yeah, the book said, "The Binutils documentation recommends building Binutils in a dedicated build directory", but I read that more as 'You *can* do this' and not 'We *expect* you to do this'. Silly me.

Comment: Yep, this did it. Thanks for pointing out my idiot mistake, haha